Javascript query API is not returning data in CosmosDB database trigger
I have created a trigger in cosmosDB that will update a document when another document is deleted within the same collection.
This is the documentation which I referred for creating this.
Here the problem is the documentation code is working fine in my environment. But the same trigger is not working in my real environment.
I was looking into it for long time. I think the issue is due to my Partition key.
While executing stored procedure, I can pass partition key also using C#.
How can I pass Partition key to a trigger?
string deletiontriggerid = "trg-UpdateUserAssignedLocations-onDelete-Facility1";
string id = "efb14ad5-198e-4e1d-b267-d48d005ed032";
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("Location:11145");


await cosmosClient
    .GetContainer(databaseId, containerId)
    .DeleteItemAsync<Location>(id,partitionKey, new ItemRequestOptions
    {
        PostTriggers = new List<string> { deletiontriggerid } 
    });

This is how I am executing the trigger. Here when I analyzed the triger code, what I understood is Javascript Query API is not returning value. At the same time, same query is reurning values when I run it directly.
To make things clear, following code works fine inside SP, but not working inside trigger.
var filterQuery = 'SELECT VALUE c FROM c JOIN a IN c.AssignedLocations WHERE a.Id = \'efb14ad5-198e-4e1d-b267-d48d005ed032\' AND c.Type=\'User\' AND c.PartitionKey=\'User:111222\'';
    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        filterQuery, 
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

Reason which I could identify is that while executing SP we can pass PartitionKey value. But I am not seeing a way we can specify partition key while invoking the operation which calls trigger.

“update a collection when another collection is deleted” - triggers don’t work this way. They are part of the same transaction as the document that caused the trigger. You cannot perform an operation in another collection.

Sorry for the miss communication @DavidMakogon. I have corrected the question.  Its "update a document when another document is deleted within the same collection"
